# Can you say Dekiba

Tags: translation, conjugations, conditionals

Can you say Dekiba as in Dekiru (to do) + ば　(the suffix for 'be able to do'), so that dekiba becomes 'if you are able to'?

Comment: 出来歯？  (filler....)

Answer (score 6):

#### The short answer

**No**, you can't say *dekiba*.  Or rather, you could indeed say that, but it's not correct and folks might not catch your intended meaning.  :)

#### The long answer

*Dekiru* is a so-called "type-2" or "vowel-stem" verb, where the stem of the vowel (the part that doesn't change when conjugating the different forms) ends in a vowel: ***deki**ru* → ***deki**nai*, ***deki**te*, ***deki**masu*, etc.  This is basically the same kind of verb as *taberu* "to eat" → ***tabe**ru*, ***tabe**nai*, ***tabe**te*, ***tabe**masu*, etc.

Other verbs are called "type-1" or "consonant-stem" verbs, where the stem ends in a consonant.  A common one you might already know is *kiku* "to hear, to listen": ***kik**u* → ***kik**anai*, ***ki**ite* (contracted from older ***kik**ite*), ***kik**imasu*, etc.

The *-ba* conditional ending requires a special *-e-* ending on the verb stem, in addition to any *-e* that's already there.  For consonant-stem verbs like *kiku*, you just take the stem *kik-*, add *-e* and then the *-ba*: ***kik**eba*.  For vowel-stem verbs like *dekiru* or *taberu*, you need to add *-re* as a special kind of stub mora (a mora is kind of like a syllable, but it's about the rhythm and time it takes to say a word -- this is very important in Japanese, with its long vowels and geminate (doubled) consonants -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mora_(linguistics)).  So for *taberu*, you'd take the stem *tabe-*, add that *-re*, and then add the *-ba*: *tabe**reba***.  Same for *dekiru*, as *deki-* + *-re* + *-ba*: *deki**reba***.

Comment: Which is why many modern linguists analyze it as *-(r)eba* and not as *ba* (though of course historically it was in fact *ba*).